# How to refer in Python to XML value between tags

Tags: python, xml

```
<rule>
    <vars>
          <value>*</value>
          <value>MAP</value>
          <value></value>
          <value>*</value>
          <value>*</value>
          <value>8795</value>
          <value>4</value>
          <value>*</value>
    </vars>
</rule>
```

This is a fragment of my XML file. I have to refer to number between value tags. I want to find and delete code between rule tags. I try to do like this:

```
x = input("if find this value delete rule block  ")
str(x)
for child in root.iter():
    for rule in child.findall('rule'):
        for vars in rule.findall('vars'):
            val = str(vars.find('value'))
            print(val)
            if val == x:
            root.remove(rule)
tree.write('output.xml')
```

So the problem is here: `val = str(vars.find('value'))`, because when I run this code and `print val` PowerShell prints:

> Element 'value' at 0x0328BFC0

for all `value` tags.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think your outer loop (`for child in root.iter()`) is not what you want, because that will iterate over *all elements in your document*. This is going to cause you to visit some nodes multiple times.

Secondly, you're seeing...

```
Element 'value' at 0x0328BFC0
```

...because you're calling `str` on the result of `vars.find('value')`,
and the `find` method returns *elements*, not strings. If you want the
text content of an element, use the `.text` attribute.  For example:

```
if value.text == x:
    ...
```

Lastly, you can only use the `remove` method on the parent of the
element you're trying to remove, so calling `root.remove()` is never
going to work.

Putting all the above together, we get something like:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('data.xml')
root = doc.getroot()
target = input('remove items with this value: ')
for rule in root.findall('rule'):
    for vars in rule.findall('vars'):
        for value in vars.findall('value'):
            if value.text == target:
                value.getparent().remove(value)

doc.write('output.xml')
```

I had to make some assumptions about your input document, so I tested
it against the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
  <rule>
    <vars>
      <value>*</value>
      <value>MAP</value>
      <value></value>
      <value>*</value>
      <value>*</value>
      <value>8795</value>
      <value>4</value>
      <value>*</value>
    </vars>
  </rule>
</document>
```

Comment: thanks, its okej and working, but You Can refer to  rule. I code like this in the same place: rule.getparent().remove(rule) and its working property